# SpriteKit: Physics bodies breaking under too much force (applyForce)

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I'm experiencing the oddest behaviour where the physicsengine has decided that walls (rectangular SKPhysicsBody) break if too many other objects (circular SKPhysicsBody) are pushing against it (using applyForce())

As far as I can tell SpriteKit has no notion of object breaking points or anything of the sort. Any ideas on how I can stop this from happening?

Note: if I change SKPhysicsBody.dynamic to FALSE, the body does not break anymore. Just to confirm that the physics engine is to blame

Video 1: Few Enemies, no break:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0I2PUeX8GHQ&feature=youtu.be

Video 2: More enemies, break:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-OkfifPCkmY&feature=youtu.be

Comment: What do you mean by "break"?

Comment: The SKNode, associated with the PhysicsBody disappears from the scene. Pretty weird huh? It takes a couple hundred bodies pushing against it for it to "break"

Comment: Can you post a video of this issue?

Comment: Yes I can. Was wondering if people would be interested enough to watch the video before answering. Later today it will be up.

Comment: Hey, videos added. have a look if you get a chance

Comment: I would interested to know if the SKPhysicsBody is equal to nil after it "breaks". The amount of force applied against a PB should be of no consequence in regards to its structure. I would run a test with a single PB and one object applying increasing force against it. If what you are saying is correct, you should be able to reach a certain point at which the break occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The higher the nodes with physics bodies, the lower the framerate.

The lower the framerate, the crazier the engine gets. One time I've even see it make some kind of blackhole.

It'll help if you lessen the force against the wall, whether gravity, or velocity from applyforce. Also making sure there's enough space for them will help.

Using precise collision detection will even lessen the framerate further.

Comment: I'm seeing all types of craziness, you're right. But it seems to happen without framerate dropping. up to 50 bodies pushing against the wall, no problem. 100+ and, the wall collapses (there is no code anywhere to destroy walls). It's driving me crazy. Will accept this answer if I don't get any thing more detailed. Thanks

Comment: Maybe it's not the framerate that's the problem. I guess it's a correlation not a cause. But anyway, make sure there's enough space for the nodes if you're creating them inside an enclosed shape.

Comment: Hey hamecanecha. Added some videos to the original question. Mind having a look?

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not sure what to say. But I can think of workaround... What if once the balls reach the walls, they stop applying force and just kind of stay in their position? So using contact delegate, you could lock their position, or remove any skaction applyforce.

Comment: That work-around crossed my mind, but requires a bit of work (when do you unlock, etc) so thought I would check why SpriteKit was misbehaving first. Will try it soon if I can't figure it out though. thanks